# Automatically apply constraints to SQLAlchemy queries

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm looking for a best approach to having a granular control over what particular `User`s can retrieve from database.

The current design implements `User` and `License` model, being a one-to-many relationship, and lots of connected entities, like `Country`, `City`, `Person` and so on. Some entities, say - `Country`, should limited to be viewed according to `License` field, so I'd like to be able to assign the view privilege for `user = User(id=1, name="Adam")`to view `france = Country(id=1, name="France")` by adding a `License(user=user, countries=[france])`. Now the tricky part is, I'd like to ruling to be applied to all queries somehow by augmenting the query with the data coming from the `License`, so setting the context basing on the `User`.

What's more, I'd like to make sure that if, for example, user would query for 10 results from `City` (which do have a FK on `Country`), the user would be only shown the cities that are within the `Countries` he has a `License` to view.

I assume there's no out-of-box SQLAlchemy extension to define such relationships, but maybe you can point me to the right direction where to hook up ruling in a such form - by subclassing query, or maybe some other way?

Ideally, the interface would allow me to do something like this: `City.query.filter(..).restrict_for(user).all()`, where `restrict_for` would be responsible for introspecting the query and applying the correct `WHERE`s according to what's being retrieved and the `License`s available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply a global filter to all tables for every query in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39852366/apply-a-global-filter-to-all-tables-for-every-query-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: Not really, as there's fairly more logic required in my case I've came up with a neat solution, will share it later.